# Ms Access as back end for asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In Asp.net can we use Ms access as back end, can we do manipulate the data if we use back end as ms access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `MSAccess`.

You will find more about [Retrieving Data Using the AccessDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e5545e1.aspx) here. Also have look at this article about [ASP.NET Data Access Overview](http://ASP.NET%20Data%20Access%20Overview) there you will find about `AccessDataSource Class`

Hope this helps

Comment: ya HuMpty duMpty thank you, i will go through the link and let me know you.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but I certainly wouldn't call MS Access directly from your asp.net code behinds.

Take a look at something like the MVC or MVP models as a place to start.  Call services which call the data layer instead of coupling your front end to any particular data store.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MS Access as your back end, yes.

I certainly wouldn't suggest it though. There are many other compact choices (such as [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)) that I would consider more stable and robust.

Comment: ya Mr. Justin Niessner, but my client asking only go for Ms acess

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Access for sure. In the past, with classic ASP, this combination was quite frequently used for small websites.

If you want to keep on using Membership, roles, ... then you can also do that with Access as there are already providers available for that. Take a look at this article on how to grab the providers and make use of it in your application: [Using Access instead of SQL server for your ASP.NET Application Services](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/UsingAccessInsteadOfSQLServerForYourASPNETApplicationServices.aspx).